# programmatically add body classes with template preprocessing

Tags: 7, theming

Is there a way to add body classes programmatically through template preprocessing without the use of a Javascript or a drupal module?

If so how would one do that? p.s. Using omega theme.

E.g.: I need to add a class to the body to change a particular background color.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add your class to body element by adding `THEMENAME_preprocess_html()` to your `template.php`
Like :

```
function MY_THEME_NAME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  // Compile a list of classes that are going to be applied to the body element.
  // This allows advanced theming based on context (home page, node of certain type, etc.).
  $variables["classes_array"][] = "blue-bg";
  $variables["attributes_array"]["class"][] = "blue-bg";// For Omega based themes
}
```

Refer this [link](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7) for more details.

Comment: On the off-chance the OP is using an Omega based theme that would be `$variables['attributes_array']['class'][] = 'blue-bg';`

Answer (score 2):

In the preprocess_html function in your template_php, you can add an item to the classes array which will render out the classes on your body. comme ca:

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_html().
 */
function YOURTHEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

  $variables['classes_array'][] = 'new-body-class';

}
```

This works on adaptive themes, and bartik based themes.